# Can't Open SPSite - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filenotfoundexception

So I try to access the TermStore of my Sharepoint 2013. I try to do it like this:

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            var site = new SPSite(GeneralConstants.TermStoreUrl);

            try
            {

                // Get a TaxonomySession from the site
                TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
                TermStore termStore = null;
                // Get a TermStore from the session
                if (session.TermStores != null && session.TermStores.Count > 0)
                {
                    termStore = session.TermStores[0];
                }

                if (termStore != null)
                {
                     //... do stuff in TermStore
```

The Problem is that as soon as I create the SPSite, I get a FileNotFoundException. Whats the problem here?
When I check the URL in the browser it works all fine and the User under which the application runs, it's a webservice by the way, has full control on the site.

Thanks for help
Greets

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? can you pinpoint which line it's not working on..? also you have partial code here can you show all relevant code that pertains to this issue..? also checkout this Blog it may help as well http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/07/runwithelevatedprivileges-watch-out-for.html

Comment: What kind of program you're making ? WebPart ? WinForm ? WPF ? Page ? APP ? Console Program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answers but I found the mistake. I used the Sharepoint.Taxonomy Namespace instead of Sharepoint.**Client**.Taxonomy

Now I works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore property of your TaxonomySession?

```
var session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
```

Also, I use PowerShell in an SP Management Window to debug my Taxonomy code logic. It helps a lot.